# Find the area of ​the CEN triangular region

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: If ABCD is a square, AB = DE.
Calculate the area of ​​the CEN triangular region.(Answer:$6m^2$)
[image]

My progress:

$S_{\triangle MCE}=X=\frac{MC⋅DC}{2}=\frac{MC⋅ℓ}{2}(I)\\
I+S_{\triangle MBA}=\frac{l^2}{2}\\
\therefore X+5 = \frac{l^2}{2}\implies 9 + S_{\triangle CEN} = \frac{l^2}{2}\\
\frac{4}{MN}=\frac{S_{\triangleÇNE}}{EN}=\frac{CN.DE}{2EN}\\
\frac{5}{BM}=\frac{4}{MC}\\
S_{ABCE} = \frac{3AB^2}{2}$

...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set: $x=BM$, $y=MC$, $s=S_{CNE}$ (in m$^2$). We have:
$$
x:y=5:(4+s),\quad
(x+y):y=s:4.
$$
Combine these to get $5:(4+s)=(s-4):4$.

Comment: Thanks for help...I don't understand your proportions...could you please clarify? Triangles $ABM$ and $CEM$ do not have the common angle to use the property you used. In the second proportion which property did you use?

Comment: @petaarantes Triangles BMA and CME have the same altitude AB, hence they are in the same ratio as their bases BM and MC. Triangles CMN and CNE have the same base CN, hence they are in the same ratio as their altitudes CM and DE.

Comment: gratitude for explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a system of $4$ equations :

$\begin{cases} \frac{l \cdot BM}{2} = 5 \\ \frac{(l -BM)\cdot CN}{2} = 4  \\  \frac{(l -BM)\cdot l}{2} = A_{CNE}+4 \\ \frac{l\cdot CN}{2} = A_{CNE} \end{cases} $

and [solve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x+*+y%29%2F2+%3D+5+%2C+%28%28x+-y%29*+z%29%2F2+%3D+4++%2C+%28%28x+-y%29*+x%29%2F2+%3D+A%2B4+++%2C+x*+z%2F2+%3D+A) for $A_{CNE}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Draw $MD$

$S_{MND} = A\\
S_{DEN}=A_x\\
AD(median)\implies {S_{AMD}} = A+ A_X\\
MDEC\implies A = S_{CNE}(by~ property)\\
S_{AMD} = \frac{l^2}{2}\implies S_{ABM}+S_{MCD}=S_{AMD} \\
\therefore  A+A_X = 5+4+A\implies A_X =9\\
\therefore MDEC: A_X.4 = A^2(by~ property)  \implies \boxed{\color{red}A = 6m^2}
$